# Is there ever a reason to NOT call Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path) on string file paths?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, api-design

It was recently requested that I accepted system Environment Variables in paths for my applications and that was really the first time that's come up for me and I didn't even realize that C# didn't just automatically resolve those.

So now I'm wondering if there is ever a situation where I wouldn't want in all my methods with path parameters that are **loading or using** (not storing) a path to do something like this:

```
public async object LoadFileAsync(string path, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null) 
{
    path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
    // proceed as normal
}
```

And if there isn't a solid reason, does anyone have any clue why .NET doesn't automatically attempt to resolve these whenever it makes I/O calls to paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExpandEnvironmentVariables` replaces *environment variables*, not just path parameters. In other words, it is not limited to things like `%SystemRoot%`, but includes every environment variable you (or one of the applications) have set.

While there are some cases where you would like to apply environment variables before performing an operation with a file, **those cases are rather limited** to the situations where you would expect an environment variable to be used in the first place. In most cases, this is absolutely not the case.

For instance, if your GUI application prompts a user to select a file to open, and then opens it, there is no reason you would like to expand environment variables, since the string would necessarily be a valid file path (although the file itself may be removed meanwhile).

Expanding environment variables automatically in .NET would therefore **violate [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)**. If I ask the application to open a file named `C:\%src%\example.txt`, I would be surprised to find that on one machine, it decided instead to try to open `C:\Program Files\Some app\source\example.txt` because on that specific machine, there was an environment variable `%src%` with `Program Files\Some app\source` as a value.

Comment: Got it, for some reason, I thought `%src%` (thinking `%` was an invalid path character) wouldn't be a valid folder name, but that's incorrect. If it was invalid though, would you still think it would violate POLA, considering that would be the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: If it were an invalid character, it would still be risky to always expand environment variables. Imagine an app which asks the user to enter a path, and the input contains the percent sign. Does it mean the user wants to use an environment variable, or that he mistyped the path? It's up to the application to decide.

Comment: From what I checked, if it doesn't resolve to an environment variable, it doesn't result in any issues. But fair point when talking about non-system variables.

Comment: @corylulu: yes, of course. But it doesn't change much to the fact that .NET cannot interpret, on behalf of the application, the intention of the user. Another example: paths coming from a template file. The percent sign may be used as a template placeholder, so one would expect an exception to be thrown if the final path contains a percent sign (since it indicates that the template wasn't applied correctly). Or in a different scenario, it may be perfectly intentional. Only your app knows which case is which: .NET cannot know that.

Comment: It makes me think of a similar discussion about path sanitization (i.e. get rid of `\..\` which are often used to exploit path traversal). Can you do it at a level of a framework? Probably not, because there are perfectly valid cases where you want to be able to have two dots followed by a backslash in your code, so if the framework forbids path traversal, it should have a parameter allowing path traversal in some cases. But then, the interface becomes more complex, while the benefit is rather limited.

Comment: SQL Injection mitigation in most SQL libraries, on the other hand, is an example of a relatively successful interface. Nearly every case where you have a dynamic query involves a string—the SQL query itself—followed by an object containing the parameters to be injected, and this is the default way to interact with the SQL library. Now, if you're really sure you want to sanitize and concatenate the query yourself, you can, but you're on your own: the library doesn't forbid you from doing it, but expects you to behave like a responsible adult.